# Matching sum values of two arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have to match both columns below. To get a match you need to sum/combine some values in TC column and combine some values in AE column. (Per sample table below - e.g-1 sum of Items 1 & 2 of TC Column (20,378) will match to the sum of items 2 & 3 of AE Column (20,378) e.-2 sum of items 15,18,19 of TC Column will match to the sum of items 12, 14, 15, 16, 20 of AE column). No single amount to sum values matching. To get a match you always need to sum values in both columns.

In my original code, these columns are stored in two different arrays. So I have to perform the loop matching inside these arrays. Hence, the reason why my code begins with storing the values in two arrays below.

This is what I want to achieve in my loop:

```
IF TCval 1 + TCval 3 = AEval1 + AEval2 + AEvall3 etc.. Then
```

Color the matched cells in yellow and remove the matched values in both arrays then re-perform the loop again.

Thanks for the help.

This what I have so far. Nested loop. Just finished 2 TC vs 2AE, 3AE etc... i need to compare up til 5 TC. Im sure there is a better way to do this.

[image: Sample Table]

```
Sub Xae2tc()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startTime As Double
    startTime = Timer

    Dim tcArrayV() As Variant, tcArrayA() As String, aeArrayV() As Variant, aeArrayA() As String
    Dim GetTcIndex As Long, i1 As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer, h As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer, o As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer, r As Integer, s As Integer
    Dim e As Integer, f As Integer, g As Integer
    Dim h1 As Integer, tcSize As Long, tcIndex As Long, aeSize As Long, aeIndex As Long
    ReDim tcArrayV(tcSize), tcArrayA(tcSize), aeArrayV(aeSize), aeArrayA(aeSize)
    Dim aeRow As Long: Dim tcRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, uTc As Integer, uAe As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    tcSize = 1: tcIndex = 0: aeSize = 1: aeIndex = 0
    aeRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count(), 4).End(xlUp).Row
    tcRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count(), 2).End(xlUp).Row

    'Store all in array
    For a = 3 To aeRow
        If ws.Cells(a, 4).Value > 0 Then
            aeArrayV(aeIndex) = CDec(ws.Cells(a, 4).Value)
            aeArrayA(aeIndex) = ws.Cells(a, 4).Address
            aeSize = aeSize + 1
            ReDim Preserve aeArrayV(aeSize)
            ReDim Preserve aeArrayA(aeSize)
            aeIndex = aeIndex + 1
        End If
    Next a

    For b = 3 To tcRow
        If ws.Cells(b, 2).Value > 0 Then
            tcArrayV(tcIndex) = CDec(ws.Cells(b, 2).Value)
            tcArrayA(tcIndex) = ws.Cells(b, 2).Address
            tcSize = tcSize + 1
            ReDim Preserve tcArrayV(tcSize)
            ReDim Preserve tcArrayA(tcSize)
            tcIndex = tcIndex + 1
        End If
    Next b

    uTc = UBound(tcArrayV) - 2
    uAe = UBound(aeArrayV) - 2

    '2:2 matching
    For h = 0 To uTc
        For i = 0 To uAe
            For j = h + 1 To uTc
                For k = i + 1 To uAe
                    If tcArrayV(h) + tcArrayV(j) = aeArrayV(i) + aeArrayV(k) Then
                        If tcArrayV(h) And tcArrayV(j) And aeArrayV(i) And aeArrayV(k) > 0 Then
                            ws.Range(tcArrayA(h)).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                            ws.Range(tcArrayA(j)).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                            ws.Range(aeArrayA(i)).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                            ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                            tcArrayV(h) = 0: tcArrayV(j) = 0: aeArrayV(i) = 0: aeArrayV(k) = 0
                            ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Offset(, 1).Value _
                            = "=" & "SUM(" & tcArrayA(h) & "," & tcArrayA(j) & ")" & "-" _
                            & "SUM(" & aeArrayA(i) & "," & aeArrayA(k) & ")"
                            ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Offset(, 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    Next h

    '2:3 matching
    For h = 0 To uTc
        For i = 0 To uAe
            For j = h + 1 To uTc
                For k = i + 1 To uAe
                    For l = k + 1 To uAe
                        If tcArrayV(h) + tcArrayV(j) = aeArrayV(i) + aeArrayV(k) + aeArrayV(l) Then
                            If tcArrayV(h) And tcArrayV(j) And aeArrayV(i) And aeArrayV(k) And aeArrayV(l) > 0 Then
                                ws.Range(tcArrayA(h)).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                                ws.Range(tcArrayA(j)).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                                ws.Range(aeArrayA(i)).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                                ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                                ws.Range(aeArrayA(l)).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                                tcArrayV(h) = 0: tcArrayV(j) = 0: aeArrayV(i) = 0: aeArrayV(k) = 0: aeArrayV(l) = 0
                                ws.Range(aeArrayA(l)).Offset(, 1).Value _
                                = "=" & "SUM(" & tcArrayA(h) & "," & tcArrayA(j) & ")" & "-" _
                                & "SUM(" & aeArrayA(i) & "," & aeArrayA(k) & "," & aeArrayA(l) & ")"
                                ws.Range(aeArrayA(l)).Offset(, 1).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next l
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    Next h

    '2:4 matching
    For h = 0 To UBound(tcArrayV) - 2
        For i = 0 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
            For j = h + 1 To UBound(tcArrayV) - 2
                For k = i + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                    For l = k + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                        For m = l + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                            If tcArrayV(h) + tcArrayV(j) = aeArrayV(i) + aeArrayV(k) + aeArrayV(l) _
                            + aeArrayV(m) Then
                                If tcArrayV(h) And tcArrayV(j) And aeArrayV(i) And aeArrayV(k) And aeArrayV(l) _
                                And aeArrayV(m) > 0 Then
                                    ws.Range(tcArrayA(h)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    ws.Range(tcArrayA(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(l)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(m)).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    tcArrayV(h) = 0: tcArrayV(j) = 0: aeArrayV(i) = 0: aeArrayV(k) = 0: aeArrayV(l) = 0
                                    aeArrayV(m) = 0
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(m)).Offset(, 1).Value _
                                    = "=" & "SUM(" & tcArrayA(h) & "," & tcArrayA(j) & ")" & "-" _
                                    & "SUM(" & aeArrayA(i) & "," & aeArrayA(k) & "," & aeArrayA(l) & "," & aeArrayA(m) & ")"
                                    ws.Range(aeArrayA(m)).Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next m
                    Next l
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    Next h


    '2:5 matching
    For h = 0 To UBound(tcArrayV) - 2
        For i = 0 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
            For j = h + 1 To UBound(tcArrayV) - 2
                For k = i + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                    For l = k + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                        For m = l + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                            For n = m + 1 To UBound(aeArrayV) - 2
                                If tcArrayV(h) + tcArrayV(j) = aeArrayV(i) + aeArrayV(k) + aeArrayV(l) _
                                + aeArrayV(m) + aeArrayV(n) Then
                                    If tcArrayV(h) And tcArrayV(j) And aeArrayV(i) And aeArrayV(k) And aeArrayV(l) _
                                    And aeArrayV(m) And aeArrayV(n) > 0 Then
                                        ws.Range(tcArrayA(h)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(tcArrayA(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(k)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(l)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(m)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(n)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                        tcArrayV(h) = 0: tcArrayV(j) = 0: aeArrayV(i) = 0: aeArrayV(k) = 0: aeArrayV(l) = 0
                                        aeArrayV(m) = 0: aeArrayV(n) = 0
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(n)).Offset(, 1).Value _
                                        = "=" & "SUM(" & tcArrayA(h) & "," & tcArrayA(j) & ")" & "-" _
                                        & "SUM(" & aeArrayA(i) & "," & aeArrayA(k) & "," & aeArrayA(l) _
                                        & "," & aeArrayA(m) & "," & aeArrayA(n) & ")"
                                        ws.Range(aeArrayA(n)).Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next n
                        Next m
                    Next l
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
    Next h

    MsgBox "Total time was: " & (Timer - startTime)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You know about `WorksheetFunctions.Sum()` ?

Comment: Is it always 2 from TC, or can it be more than 2 rows? And are the values sequential in the match, or could they be separate rows. Can you share gdoc sheet with some sample values so we don't have to type anything in? Or a csv file or something textual instead of an image.

Comment: @ja72. I do not know worksheetfuctions.sum. I haven't used it yet.

Comment: @ja72 - It is not always 2 TC. Max is 5 TC 5AE.

Comment: @ja72 I've edited the post to show the nested loop I created. it works but it is long and slow. I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Im still at 2 TC vs XAE. I still need to do up to 5 TC

Comment: And the values in TC are sequential for each match, or can be dispersed around? Also please post text values for sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested some code that seems to work up to 5 combinations, at least with my made up values. The sample below runs in about 5 seconds.

In my case TC values start at `[D6]`, and AE values start at `[E6]`. I chose to display the results by showing which AE values (by index) is used for each TC value in a table starting at `[G6]`. All these ranges can be changed in the code

[image: scr]

### Sheet1 Code

```
Option Explicit    

Public Sub MatchAETest()

    Dim r_tc As Range, r_ae As Range, r_index As Range

    Set r_tc = Range("D6") ' First data cell for TC
    Set r_ae = Range("E6") ' First data cell for AE

    Dim n_tc As Long, n_ae As Long
    n_tc = Range(r_tc, r_tc.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    n_ae = Range(r_ae, r_ae.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Set r_index = Range("G6") ' First cell of index table

    ' Pull values into memory
    Dim y_tc() As Variant, x_ae() As Variant
    y_tc = r_tc.Resize(n_tc, 1).Value2
    x_ae = r_ae.Resize(n_ae, 1).Value2

    ' Set a table of processed values in AE
    ' Contains the index in TC value is used in
    Dim found_ae() As Boolean
    ReDim found_ae(1 To n_ae) ' Defaults all to 0

    ' How many values of AE to look for max.
    Const depth As Long = 5

    Dim i_tc As Long, ps As Variant, n_comb As Long
    Dim ae_index() As Long

    ' k is # of combinations considered up to `depth`
    Dim k As Long
    ' Make sure the #combinations does not exceed #AE
    n_comb = WorksheetFunction.Min(depth, n_ae)
    For k = 2 To n_comb
        Call FillAEIndex(ae_index, k)
        Do
            ' Check if current combination contains
            ' any index of found AE
            If Not AnyMatched(ae_index, found_ae) Then
                ' Get sum of combination
                ps = PartialSum(x_ae, ae_index)
                ' Check if sum exists in TC
                i_tc = IndexOf(y_tc, ps)
                If i_tc > 0 Then
                    ' Found a match
                    Debug.Print "MATCH: Sum(" & Join(",", ae_index) & ") = TC(" & i_tc & ") = " & ps
                    r_index.Cells(i_tc, 1).Resize(1, k).Value = ae_index
                    Call SetMatched(ae_index, found_ae)
                End If
                If AllFound(found_ae) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until NextCombination(ae_index, found_ae)
        DoEvents
    Next k

End Sub



Public Function PartialSum(ByRef ae() As Variant, ByRef ae_index() As Long) As Variant
' Sum up all the values in AE specified in ae_index
' Example: ae=(10,20,30,40), ae_index=(1,3) => 10+30=40
    Dim ps As Variant
    ps = 0#
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ae_index)
        ps = ps + ae(ae_index(i), 1)
    Next i
    PartialSum = ps
End Function

Public Sub FillAEIndex(ByRef ae_index() As Long, ByVal level As Long)
' Initialize ae_index = (1,2,..k)
    ReDim ae_index(1 To level)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To level
        ae_index(i) = i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function AnyMatched(ByRef ae_index() As Long, ByRef found_ae() As Boolean) As Boolean
' Search ae_index if any value is a match already in found_ae

    Dim done As Boolean, i As Long
    done = False
    For i = 1 To UBound(ae_index)
        If found_ae(ae_index(i)) Then
            done = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    AnyMatched = done
End Function

Public Function AllMatched(ByRef ae_index() As Long, ByRef found_ae() As Boolean) As Boolean
' Search ae_index if all values have a match already in found_ae
    Dim done As Boolean, i As Long
    done = True
    For i = 1 To UBound(ae_index)
        If Not found_ae(ae_index(i)) Then
            done = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    AllMatched = done
End Function

Public Function AllFound(ByRef found_ae() As Boolean) As Boolean
' Check if all values of found_ae are true
    Dim done As Boolean, i As Long
    done = True
    For i = 1 To UBound(found_ae)
        If Not found_ae(i) Then
            done = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    AllFound = done
End Function

Public Sub SetMatched(ByRef ae_index() As Long, ByRef found_ae() As Boolean)
' Set found_ae with all values from ae_index
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ae_index)
        found_ae(ae_index(i)) = True
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function NextCombination(ByRef ae_index() As Long, ByRef found_ae() As Boolean) As Boolean
' Increment values in ae_index until it uses a combination that contains
' non of the AE values that have already being match, according to
' found_ae array. Also if all possible combinations is exhausted
' then return true to terminate the process.

    Dim done As Boolean, flip As Boolean
    Dim j As Long, n_ae As Long, jj As Long, k As Long
    k = UBound(ae_index)
    n_ae = UBound(found_ae)
    done = True
    Do
        For j = k To 1 Step -1
            If ae_index(j) < n_ae Then
                ae_index(j) = ae_index(j) + 1
                    For jj = j + 1 To k
                        ae_index(jj) = jj
                    Next jj
                done = False
                flip = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not flip Then Exit Do
        If AnyMatched(ae_index, found_ae) Then
            flip = False
        End If
    Loop While Not flip
    NextCombination = done
End Function

Public Function IndexOf(ByRef tc() As Variant, ByVal x As Variant) As Long
' Search array for value, or return 0 if not found
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tc, 1)
        If tc(i, 1) = x Then
            IndexOf = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IndexOf = 0
End Function

Public Function Join(ByVal sep As String, ByRef values As Variant) As String
' Create a string by joining the string values of an array and combining them
' with a separator string.
' Example: Join("-",Array(1,2,3)) = "1-2-3"
    Dim i As Long, i_start As Long, i_end As Long
    i_start = LBound(values)
    i_end = UBound(values)
    Dim s As String
    s = vbNullString
    For i = i_start To i_end
        If i > i_start Then
            s = s & sep
        End If
        s = s & CStr(values(i))
    Next i
    Join = s
End Function
```

### Debug Output

```
MATCH: Sum(1,4) = TC(2) = 20611
MATCH: Sum(2,5) = TC(1) = 20819
MATCH: Sum(3,6) = TC(4) = 20965
MATCH: Sum(8,14) = TC(5) = 19717
MATCH: Sum(9,18) = TC(6) = 18889
MATCH: Sum(12,17) = TC(8) = 40405
MATCH: Sum(13,20) = TC(9) = 32398
MATCH: Sum(7,10,16) = TC(3) = 22876
MATCH: Sum(11,15,19) = TC(7) = 48512
MATCH: Sum(21,22,23,24) = TC(10) = 90421
MATCH: Sum(25,26,27,28,29) = TC(11) = 89504
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I have learned something new from you. I tested your code and it can only do combination (Xsum of AE) to single value of TC?  I tried 2:3 matching 2TC and 3AE with your code but it is not working.

Comment: You are correct, I thought that was the design goal, to match 1 value of TC to a sum of AE. My mistake, but now the problem is much harder to deal with, and a lot more time consuming. You want to check up to five combinations of AE against five combinations of TC?